# Moving file security from one server to another (asp.net sites, IIS)

Tags: windows, security, iis, asp.net, files

I am running windows server with asp.net websites and sql server 2008 and IIS 6. 
It is working fine.

Now I need to move my asp.net websites to another windows server and I have hard time setting correct file security for the new server.

Is there any way to compare or move or see difference file security between two servers?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [XCACLS](http://ss64.com/nt/xcalcs.html) to dump the permissions on both directories to text files and then a diff application (e.g. [WinDiff](http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm)) to compare them.

Alternatively you could use robocopy.exe to copy the from source to destination and preserve the permissions.

Comment: We have a Web infrastructure with Dev>Test>Staging>Production and I use the Robocopy option to keep the files/permissions in sync.  +1 for an old fav